# Why some alpha + Evaluate return Pod, some return only return an Entity?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

#### Why some alpha + Evaluate return Pod, some return only return an Entity?

---

Here is an example

One guess is some direct match/index will return a Entity, if with some NLP of Input, then will return Pod

something like: `If[EntityQ,Return@Entity,NLP@Return@Pod]`

[image]

[image]

Comment: I also get an entity. But Wolfram|Alpha output can depend on context and your location, so that might be the reason why you got something else ...

Comment: Click on the expansion `>>` symbol next to the name

Comment: Isn't it just that some entities don't have representations in Mathematica? WolframAlpha has a broader internal representation system than Mathematica does.

Comment: @Bob Maybe, when the result is too large, we should expand the result manullay by clicking on the expansion.

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using and what does `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {PrivateFrontEndOptions, 
  "WolframAlphaSettings"}]` return?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're crossing types of input

[image]

For Me, '=' and ctl + '=' return no pod, just an entity- and '==' always returns a pod.

Comment: My Inputs are all in `=` mode, you can see my pictures, they're all non-star `=`

Answer (score 0):

Prefer not to say, more than a perception, but an answer...

On OSX 10.11 and Mathematica 10.0.2.0 no problems so far

[image]

Comment: Just curious, What happened 2013 that made people so interested in Richard III?

Comment: @PerAlexandersson See [The Discovery of Richard III](https://www.le.ac.uk/richardiii/) and [Exhumation and reburial of Richard III of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhumation_and_reburial_of_Richard_III_of_England), [livescience: King Richard III](http://www.livescience.com/topics/king-richard-iii/)